# Using python ctypes with 32 bit library

Tags: python, ctypes

When I try to import a simple ctype module that loads a 32bit library I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "simple_test.py", line 5, in <module>
    _myLib = ctypes.CDLL(_path + _file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 353, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: ../../bin/mylib.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

also happens with python 3.3.

The issue here is that I DON'T want to re-compile my lib as 64bit,
is there a way I can make it work?

Thanks,
Keren

Comment: The library and Python need to be built for the same architecture. If you won't or can't rebuild the library, then you need to use 32-bit Python. The Python packages on Debian-based distros are `Multi-Arch: allowed` instead of `Multi-Arch: same`, so the i386 and amd64 Python packages cannot coexist. In this case you either have to build your own 32-bit version of Python or use a 32-bit chroot.

Comment: Is there a flag to python interpreter to tell it to run as 32 bit?

Comment: No, it doesn't work like that. amd64 and i386 are different [instruction set architectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set). An ELF binary has to be compiled for one or the other. If Linux used an ELF [fat binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_binary) format, then maybe in theory one could dynamically select the ISA when running a program. But the reality you have to live with in Linux (and Windows) is separate builds and separate filesystem paths for different architectures.

Answer (score 3):

You simply cannot load 32-bit code into a 64-bit application, and vice versa. Your options are:

1. Swap to using a 32-bit interpreter
2. Keep using a 64-bit interpreter, but use `multiprocessing` so as to allow your 64-bit interpreter to communicate with the 32-bit interpreter.
3. Recompile your 32-bit library into a 64-bit library

The first two options suffer from the problem, that on debian-based distributions 32-bit interpreters and 64-bit interpreters cannot be installed at the same time using the package manager (see eryksun's comment).

Recompiling the library is almost certainly to be the easier option, and definitely don't suffer a runtime overhead.

An example of how to do number (2). Be forewarned this will incur high overheads for sending data back and forth if you are using these methods a lot, or with large inputs/outputs.

## main.py

```
# example using the standard c library
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE 
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
import atexit

p = Popen(["/path/to/32-bit/python", "/path/to/delegate.py"], stdout=PIPE)

atexit.register(p.terminate)

port = int(p.stdout.readline())
authkey = p.stdout.read()

m = BaseManager(address=("localhost", port), authkey=authkey)
m.connect()

# tell manager to expect an attribute called LibC
m.register("LibC")

# access and use libc
libc = m.LibC()
print(libc.abs(-2))
```

### delegate.py

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
from ctypes import c_int, cdll
from os import closerange, write

# setup library
libc = cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.so.6")

# tell ctypes how to call function
libc.abs.argtypes = c_int,
libc.abs.restype = c_int

# wrapper for access to the functions
class LibC:
    abs = staticmethod(libc.abs)

# setup manager
manager = BaseManager(address=("localhost", 0))
manager.register("LibC", LibC)

server = manager.get_server()
# tell caller the port and auth key to access the manager with
write(1, str(server.address[1]).encode("ascii"))
write(1, b"\n")
write(1, server.authkey) # write raw authkey bytes
closerange(0, 3) # close stdin, stdout, stderr

server.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 3):

There is also the (relatively) new [MSL-LoadLib](http://msl-loadlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) that you could use.

Its basically what Dunes describe with his example, but comes bundled with a python32, so you don't have to deal with that.